# Jenkins declarative pipeline get environment variable at post stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am getting runtime value in build stage stage which I stored in an environment variable . I saved that to env.cfg file under WORKSPACE .

Now I am trying to get that value in post pipeline step to be used in email communication. I tried load method but it did not work

Any help ?

post {
always {
echo $SNAPSHOT / /this always comes null
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you can access an environment variable across the pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    environment {
        MESSAGE="Hello World"
    }
    stages {
        stage('one') {
            steps {
                echo "${env.MESSAGE}"
                sh "echo $MESSAGE"
                script {
                    print env.MESSAGE
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo "${env.MESSAGE}"
            script {
                print env.MESSAGE
            }
        }
        failure {
            echo "${env.MESSAGE}"
            script {
                print env.MESSAGE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but as per your scenario let say I have a file called `.env` with the content below in the current Jenkins job WORKSPACE and I want to read and make this env variable in the pipeline.

**.env**

```
export SNAPSHOT=1.0.0
export MESSAGE='Hello World'
export MESSAGE_FROM_ENV_FILE='Hello From .env file'
```

your pipeline should look like

**scripted pipeline**

```
node {
    stage('one') {
        sh """
          source $WORKSPACE/.env
          
          echo \$SNAPSHOT
          echo \$MESSAGE
          echo \$MESSAGE_FROM_ENV_FILE
        """
        
    }
}
```

**declarative pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh """
                  source $WORKSPACE/.env
          
                  echo \$SNAPSHOT
                  echo \$MESSAGE
                  echo \$MESSAGE_FROM_ENV_FILE
                """
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            sh """
                  source $WORKSPACE/.env
          
                  echo \$SNAPSHOT
                  echo \$MESSAGE
                  echo \$MESSAGE_FROM_ENV_FILE
            """
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a global variable:

```
SNAPSHOT = ""
println "SNAPSHOT is ${SNAPSHOT}"

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    println "SNAPSHOT is ${SNAPSHOT}"
                    SNAPSHOT = "Modified"
                    println "SNAPSHOT is now ${SNAPSHOT}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo "${SNAPSHOT}"
        }
    }
}
```